# Let $Y$ be a dense subspace of a nls $X$. Show that $Y^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X^*$.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, dual-spaces

> Let $Y$ be a dense subspace of a normed linear space $X$. Show that $Y^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X^*$.

Define $F : Y^* \to X^*$ as  $F(f\mid_Y) = f$.

Clearly the map $F$ is an isometry. And the extension is unique due to the fact that if $f$ is a continuous linear functional and $Y \subseteq X$ is a dense subspace such that $f|_Y = 0$, then $f = 0$. Thus the map is well defined.

Clearly $F$ is bijective and $F^{-1}$ also exists clearly. Thus we can say that $F$ is an isomorphism and isometry.

Is the above argument correct?

---

Note: Given two normed vector spaces $V$ and $W$, a isometry is a map $f : V \to W$ that preserves the norms i.e. $\mid \mid f(v) \mid \mid = \mid \mid u \mid\mid$.

Comment: You've definitely ticked all boxes to prove isometric isomorphism. But if I were to nitpick (as grading a hw), I'd ask justification for why every element of $Y^*$ is of the form $f\mid_Y$ and why $F$ is an isometry.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Is the argument correct?

Comment: You showed the extension is unique, but you should also explain why it exists.

Comment: @NateEldredge With help of Hahn Banach Extension we can say that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $f: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ by Hahn-Banach there is some extension $\overline{f}:X \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\|f\| = \|\overline{f}\|$. 
This extension is unique as $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ is dense. So there is a well-defined isometry $F: Y^\ast \to X^ast$ defined by $F(f) = \overline{f}$. As usual, the unicity implies that $F$ is linear as well. And the map that sends $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ to $f|Y : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is its obvious inverse, so $F$ is onto, as well.